# Is there an RDP client that can work with a dual monitor setup?

Tags: 13.10, windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a  Windows Hyper-V Server setup. On the Hyper-V Server we have Windows 7 Pro 32 Bit installed. On Ubuntu it comes with [Remmina](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/remmina/) RDP client by default. I like the default RDP client, however I can't use two monitors with it. Both monitors are installed on my Ubuntu 13.10 32 Bit system. Both monitors work great inside Ubuntu, I just need them both to work with an RDP client. Is there any other RDP client that will work with two monitors? Or can I configure remmina to work with them both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `rdesktop -f` or run `rdesktop -f <width>x<height>`.

> **-f**
>
> Enable fullscreen mode. This overrides the window manager and causes the rdesktop window to fully cover the current screen. Fullscreen mode can be toggled at any time using Ctrl-Alt-Enter.
>
> **-g**  Desktop geometry (WxH). 
>   If geometry is the special word "workarea", the geometry will be fetched from the extended window
>   manager hints property _NET_WORKAREA, from the root window. The
>   geometry can also be specified as a percentage of the whole screen,
>   e.g. "-g 80%".

Recently I read about [FreeRDP](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP). I should support multimonitors, but I have no experiences with it.

Comment: I have multimonitor and neither of those options work. `-f` uses up both screens; `-g 90%`  produces a massively wide window. The only way I could get it to work was to explicitly use `-g 1800x1080` and avoid fullscreen mode.

Comment: This allows you to span the window across multiple monitors, but it doesn't allow you to use true multimonitor support like FreeRDP does, so I don't think it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to compile [FreeRDP](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) from sources because Multi-Monitor support is only available in versions >= 1.1.

Visit this [page](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation) to get instructions and a list a build dependencies.

Then you'll be able to start a connection from a terminal like this:

```
xfreerdp /multimon /u:username /v:server_hostname:server_port
```

Comment: This is an answer from 2014; the xfreerdp suppliued with my Ubuntu 18.04 supports this.